# Passing Values Through Excel sheet in Ruby-watir

Tags: ruby

```
 require 'watir-webdriver'
 require 'win32ole'
 require 'roo'


 b= Watir::Browser.new(:firefox)
 b.goto('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2')
 xl = WIN32OLE.new('excel.application')
 wrkbook= xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Excel\\mondial1.xlsx")

 wrksheet= wrkbook.Worksheets(1)
 wrksheet.Select

 username1= wrksheet.Range("a1").Value
 password1= wrksheet.Range("b1").Value

 b.text_field(:id, "Email").set("username1")
 b.text_field(:id, "Passwd").set("password1")
 b.button(:id, "signIn").click

 xl.Quit
```

I just want to open a Excel sheet and get values from there and i need to provide that as a input to textfield in gmail.

**instead of getting values from Excel sheet** **It sets as "username1" directly** **I need to pass values through Excel**   Please provide your suggestion, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue**

In the line

```
 b.text_field(:id, "Email").set("username1")
```

You are passing a string "username1" to the `set` method. This is why that is the value that is typed into the text field.

**Solution**

What you actually want to do is pass the value of the variable `username1`. This is done by making it the parameter of the `set` method.

```
b.text_field(:id, "Email").set(username1)
```

Notice that there are no quotations around the `username1`. Similar would be required for the `password1` variable.

Comment: Tat Works Fine...Thank U Justin